# How to select an element loaded through the jQuery load() function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I am currently having trouble with the following (here is some sample code first):

```
<div id="container"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#container').load('content.html');

    $('.elementInContentHTML').fadeIn();
</script>
```

In short, I want to be able to access elements that have been dynamically added to a page without attaching them to event handlers.

I know about the `live()` method, but I **do not** want to bind my action to any event, i.e. I just want to run some actions with these new elements without clicking them, focusing, blurring, etc.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `load` function is asynchronous.
Your next line runs before the content is loaded.

You need to put your code inside the `load` function's callback, so that it will only run after the new content is loaded:

```
$('#container').load('content.html', function() {
    $('.elementInContentHTML').fadeIn();
});
```

Answer (score 5):

You could try using the callback for when load completes? See http://api.jquery.com/load/

```
$('#result').load('ajax/test.html', function() {
  alert('Load was performed.');
});
```