# Initializing FitVids plugin on Fancybox modal content

Tags: jquery, fancybox-2, fitvids

I'm trying to initialize the [FitVids](http://fitvidsjs.com/) plugin on [Fancybox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) modal content once that content is loaded. It works perfectly if I use the `onUpdate` callback for when the user resizes the viewport, but if I try to get it working with `afterShow` to apply it once the content is shown, I get nothing. I've tested to ensure that `afterShow` works by throwing in `console.log('whatever')` and that was successful.

**This is the code I'm using:**

```
$('.tile-link.fancybox').click(function() {
    var url = $(this).data('url');
    var getContent = $('.tile-lightbox-content').load(url + ' #lightboxBucketContent');
    $('.tile-lightbox-content').empty();

    $.fancybox({
        content: getContent,
        width: '90%',
        height: '90%',
        type: 'html',
        scrolling: 'no',
        modal: false,
        padding: 20,
        enableEscapeButton: true,
        titleShow: true,
        autoSize: false,
        autoResize: true,
        autoDimensions: false,
        aspectRatio: true,
        helpers: {
            media: true
        },
        // afterShow doesn't work
        afterShow: function() {
            $('.fancybox-inner').fitVids({
                customSelector: 'iframe[src^="http://somewebsite.com"]'
            });
        },
        // onUpdate works correctly
        onUpdate: function() {
            $('.fancybox-inner').fitVids({
                customSelector: 'iframe[src^="http://somewebsite.com"]'
            });
        }
    });
});
```

I'm using this on a WordPress website where content is loaded into some masonry tiles that trigger a fancybox modal window when clicked and load a portion of a page via the jQuery `load` function. Everything works dandy with the exception of the FitVids. The tile modal content often contains iframe video embeds and I need them to cooperate on touch/mobile devices.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: just curious : do you really need FitVids?, don't videos scale inside fancybox "out of the box"? try the examples at http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#examples --> Extended functionality --> media helper

Comment: @JFK I was thinking the same thing but that helper only seems to accomodate for providers like YouTube, Vimeo, Metacafe, etc. It also works for those items when the `href` of the fancybox URL is directly to the media item itself. With my situation, the modal boxes contain text content that the user writes in the WYSIWYG of a WordPress post and an embedded (`iframe`) video that is pulled from a third party source that is not one of the mainstream providers listed under the media helper. My client uses a CDN for presenting media and other things to potential clients and publicly.

Comment: If you are actually loading the content as `inline, try initializing FitVids as a callback of the `.load()` method and I guess that would work for what you are trying to do with `afterShow`

Comment: @JFK Something [similar to this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3973933/jquery-load-callback-function)? I hadn't thought of that. That's worth trying.

Comment: @JFK dude, you're the best. I found something that works. Posting the solution now. Thanks for getting me on the right track.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After tinkering with this for a while trying to figure out why `afterShow` didn't work but `onUpdate` did, JFK was able to point me in the right direction and the selected answer to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5262640/jquery-add-functionality-to-element-after-load) got me squared away.

Here's the code that works for me:

```
$('.tile-link.fancybox').click(function() {
    var url = $(this).data('url');
    var getContent = $('.tile-lightbox-content').load(url + ' .lightboxBucketContent', function() {
        $('.lightboxBucketContent').find('.lightbox-video-wrap').each( function(i) {
            $(this).fitVids({
                customSelector: 'iframe[src^="https://somewebsite.com"], iframe[src^="http://somewebsite.com"]'
            });
        });
    });
    $('.tile-lightbox-content').empty();

    $.fancybox({
        width: '90%',
        height: '90%',
        content: getContent,
        type: 'html',
        scrolling: 'no',
        modal: false,
        padding: 20,
        enableEscapeButton: true,
        titleShow: true,
        autoScale: true,
        autoSize: false,
        autoResize: true,
        autoDimensions: false,
        aspectRatio: true,
        helpers: {
            media: true
        },
        onUpdate: function() {
            $('.fancybox-inner').each( function(i) {
                $(this).fitVids({
                    customSelector: 'iframe[src^="https://somewebsite.com"], iframe[src^="http://somewebsite.com"]'
                });
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Instead of trying to tie the function to Fancybox script itself, JFK suggested tying it to the `load()` function instead. After some fiddling, that did the trick. So now it will:

1. Load the content fragment from the URL specified in the `data-url` parameter of my `a` element (`<a data-url="http://somewebsiteurl.com">...`)
2. Find the container within the loaded content that I want to apply FitVids to
3. Apply FitVids to every iterance of the container that contains the `iframe` embed

I also duplicated the same function into the `onUpdate` callback of Fancybox so that if the user resizes their browser and clicks on a tile that triggers the modal, it will make sure that FitVids is applied after that viewport change. I don't think this part is crucial but it's there.

This is the only thing that has worked for me up to this point so I'm pretty excited. JFK, I owe you a beer (or whatever you prefer).

Comment: @JFK it says I can accept my own answer in 13 hours. Seriously, thanks for your help. If you use PayPal I owe you a beer.