# jQuery find element on page when using load(), that are outside of element you load into

Tags: javascript, jquery

Alright, I have a page that makes use of `load()` for one of the elements on that page. Which generally works fine. However theres a new feature being added in, and I've done stumped myself. So this is how it works, the page is php/html when the page loads (the parent not the element in question) it adds an element to the page that only exists in a particular instance of the product, when one specific piece of criteria is met.. So with that the element that uses `load()` needs to see if that element is on the page.

Normally I'd use something like

```
if($('#element').length > 0)
{
   //found, do something
}
```

I am typically not a fan of load myself, but this is how the system was built initially and a lot of other things tie into this existing feature. So rewriting it is not an option currently.

Anyway what I am finding out now is that its not finding the element I need to find in the parent elements that rendered initially. my little if-else up there won't work. So I am wondering is there a work around for this?

***EDIT***
The html I am talking about I will try to elaborate on here to express where the issue is.

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title></title>
   </head>
   <body>

Everything in here initially renders server-side.
In the event a particular case is found the php also renders an addition div
<div id="specialDiv">some text</div>
Link Link Link Link Link
<div id="elementwithLoad">
   when a link outside of this element is clicked (just for sake of example).
   the jquery load() event is fired off, and loads an external html file.
   its from within this element that I need to find "specialDiv" thats sitting on the outside of this element.
   which doesn't seem to be working through the normal means of my above if-else which is placed inside of this HTML file.
</div>

   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4450825/how-to-select-an-element-loaded-through-the-jquery-load-function-with-jquery

Comment: Unfortunately no, not a dupe. That is discussing how to make the element load in a particular way. of which I can usually handle elements within the loaded one, it just seems that the elements outside of the loaded one are unacceptable to me at the moment. Ill Edit my post to try and show the HTML in some respect of what I mean

Comment: mind posting your js? it might give me a better idea of structure