# How to capture a new group of selector after loading a div with .load() of Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently, my website http://benoitmignault.ca/english/english.html works well on Chrome or Firefox, but on IE the fetch functions doesn't work...

I started to understand Jquery because the .load () function works well on IE because the fetch function doesn't work...

I managed to display each of my links in the "header" section in the div_center section.

When I click on the pictures section, my 5 links are displayed.
When I come to click on one of the 5 pictures it does not display the content in the section «div_photo», but rather the content of the page html is displayed as a new page ...

```
const listeSections = document.querySelectorAll('.header div a');
function affichageSection(){
$(listeSections).each(function(){
    $(this).on('click', function(evt){            
        evt.preventDefault();            
        if (evt.target.href === "http://localhost:8080/english/english.html"){
            window.location.assign("/english/english.html");
        } else if (evt.target.href === "http://localhost:8080/index.html"){
            window.location.assign("/index.html");
        } else if (evt.target.href === "http://localhost:8080/pageAccueuil/partie_photos_EN.html"){
            $(div_Center).load(evt.target.href);
            affichageSectionPhoto();
        } else {
            $(div_Center).load(evt.target.href);                
            $(div_Photo).append("");
        }  
    });
});
```

}

This is my function that does not work well and I can not understand where my mistake is, it's been days that I'm going around in circles ...

```
function affichageSectionPhoto(){
var allListElements = $(".unePassionPhoto a");
$(div_Center).find(allListElements).each(function(){
    $(this).on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(div_Photo).load(e.target.href);
        }
    });
});
```

}

Here is the portion of my code from my index.html page:

```
         <div class="middle"> 
            <div class="header">
                <div><a href="pageAccueuil/partie_accueuil.html">Accueil</a>
                 </div>
                <div><a href="pageAccueuil/partie_projets.html">Projets</a>
                 </div>
                <div><a href="pageAccueuil/partie_photos.html">Photos</a>
                 </div>
                <div><a href="pageAccueuil/partie_aPropos.html">À propos</a>
                 </div>
                <div><a href="english/english.html">English</a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="center"></div>  
            <div class="photo"></div>                
        </div>
```

I tried to find the information on https://learn.jquery.com/ but without success or to use the "console.log ()" function

thank you in advance

This is my console.log(div_Center)
[My console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EVCq.jpg)

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$(div_Center).find(".unePassionPhoto a")`?

Comment: I already try it...                                    $(div_Center).find(".unePassionPhoto a").each(function(){
        console.log(this);

the result is null...

Comment: try `console.log(div_Center)` there, you will probably see it does not exist.

Comment: First, thx to help me...I m a beginnner programmer.
I upload the result of my console.log with a screenshoot at this end of my post...

Comment: Please let us know what version of jquery you are using.

Comment: Of course ! 
I put these link in my index.html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

Maybe, at the moment i try to collect the information of 
var allListElements = $(".unePassionPhoto a"); the information isn't already in my div_center...

I know that if we use the function fetch with JS we need to put our code inside of the fetch...Maybe with .load() it's the same patern....

Unfortunately, i m going to work, so i will respond until 5pm.

Comment: I found the solution on this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4450825/how-to-select-an-element-loaded-through-the-jquery-load-function

I forgot .load is asynchronous, so i must put my stuff right after the completed function load with 

$(div_Center).load(evt.target.href, function() {
                    affichageSectionPhoto();
});