# Update element in another HTML file retrieved with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to add this feature to my nav bar https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sticky_header.asp.

The difference is that my website has the header in another HTML file called *menu.html* and it is imported using jquery, more precisely this command.

`$(function (){
    $("#header").load("/structureFiles/menu.html");
});`

Moreover, this function is in a separate .js file with the function to add the "sticky" bar

```
window.onload= function(){
   var topNav = document.getElementById("topMenu");
   var sticky = topNav.offsetTop;
   console.log("top menu: " + sticky);
}
```

When I try to retrieve the element using `getElementById`i obtain
`Cannot read property 'offsetTop' of null`. 
On the other hand, if I try to use jquery with `$(window).scroll`, the element offset is always zero. Any idea?

Comment: I'd start by changing `window.onload` to `$(document).ready()` and see if that makes a difference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698200/window-onload-vs-document-ready

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select an element loaded through the jQuery load() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4450825/how-to-select-an-element-loaded-through-the-jquery-load-function)

Comment: ^ `.load()` is asynchronous. You need to wait until the content has loaded before trying to target it.

Comment: Nothing changed, i continue to get Cannot read property 'offsetTop' of null. Seems like that i can't retrieve an element imported from another file

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried something like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    $("#header").css(
    {
        position: $("#header").offset().top - window.scrollY > window.scrollY ? 
            "fixed" : "static",
        top: 0
    });
});
```

Comment: I don'r want manipulate the css of #header element but of the element inside it that i'm going to load using jquery